# Duas AsyncTask executando paralelamente fazendo requisição com HttpClient

Tags: java, android, http

Tenho duas classes extendendo AsyncTask, nas quais elas me retornam um JSON de um server. Estou usando o seguinte código para executá-las simultaneamente:

```js
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    AsyncTaskExemplo1.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, "");
else
    contact.execute("");

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    AsyncTaskExemplo2.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, "");
else
    contact.execute("");
```

Utilizo o seguinte código para criar a minha conexão:

```java
public static HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
public JSONObject GET(String url, JSONObject jsonObject) {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONObject jArray = null;
    try {
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        if (jsonObject != null) {
            String json = "";
            json = jsonObject.toString();
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
            ((HttpResponse) httpGet).setEntity(se);
        }
        httpGet.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpGet.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
        if (inputStream != null) {
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        } else {
            result = "Did not work!";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    if (result != null) {
        try {
            jArray = new JSONObject(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return jArray;
}
```

Quando executo as AsyncTask uma após a outra, elas me retornam os JSONs corretamente, entretanto se as executo simultaneamente UMA delas não espera o retorno do servidor e continua a execução retornando nulo na função 'GET' do meu código.

Já li que o Android não aceita duas requisições http simultâneas com a biblioteca HttpClient padrão da Apache.

Por favor, se alguém já enfrentou uma situação parecida e puder me ajudar, fico muito agradecido.

Comment: Te aconselho a usar uma biblioteca tipo a [Volley](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728) (recomendada pelo google) e esquecer que threads existem.

Comment: eu sei que não é exatamente uma resposta, mas assim como o @ExceptionAl eu recomendo vc deixar essas asynctasks e usar uma lib. Só que minha recomendação é outra lib, ela é a loopj http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ "instagram e pinterest usam ela"

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas. Eu até cheguei a implementar um código utilizando a loopj, porém ela ainda tem alguns bugs e eu acabei enfrentando um deles, infelizmente sem solução. Encontrei uma ótima lib chamada [robospice](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice). Ainda estou fazendo alguns testes, mas ele promete muito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação do Android

> public final AsyncTask execute (Params... params)
>
> Note: this function schedules the task on a queue for a single background thread or pool of threads depending on the platform version. When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting HONEYCOMB, tasks are back to being executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution. If you truly want parallel execution, you can use the executeOnExecutor(Executor, Params...) version of this method with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR; however, see commentary there for warnings on its use.

Desta forma, não é possível rodar mais de uma AsyncTask em paralelo.
Asynctasks são utilizadas para facilitar a utilização de Threads, uma vez que permitem modificações na UI. Entretanto é possível obter o mesmo efeito utilizando Threads convencionais aliado a algum mecanismo de comunicação com a thread principal.
A documentação do android apresenta um bom tutorial sobre o assunto no link
http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Comment: Depois do Honeycomb é possível rodar até 5 AsyncTasks ao mesmo tempo. O problema ocorre quando 2 ou mais AsyncTask fazem alguma requisição http. O Android só executa uma por vez e se chamo as Async com o executeOnExecutor a aplicação da crash.